# How do I select rows that are not matched on specific column (sqlite)

Tags: sql, sqlite

Ok hopefully my table works, I've never posted here before, but I'm trying to find who has received doses of more than one type of vaccine from this table (all details are dummy data, not real people or id numbers etc)

| NHI_id | fname | lname | vaccine_name | vac_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16120428 | Clayton | Marsh | Comirnaty | 2021-03-20 |
| 16120428 | Clayton | Marsh | Janssen | 2021-04-01 |
| 16120430 | Dillon | Richards | Comirnaty | 2021-03-20 |
| 16120430 | Dillon | Richards | Comirnaty | 2021-04-10 |
| 16120432 | Giselle | Miles | Janssen | 2021-04-15 |
| 16120433 | Taylor | Buckley | Comirnaty | 2021-03-20 |
| 16120434 | Kermit | Greene | Janssen | 2021-04-15 |
| 16120435 | Harrison | Dorsey | Janssen | 021-04-15 |

So Clayton March is the only person who has received doses of different vaccines and I'm trying show that with a query. I got the above table with the following query:

```sql
SELECT NHI_id, fname, lname, vaccine_name, vac_date
FROM Patients
NATURAL JOIN Vaccinations
NATURAL JOIN Vaccines
```

and I've been able to query everyone who has received two doses of any vaccine, but I'm having trouble then narrowing it down to doses of DIFFERENT vaccines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```sql
SELECT NHI_id, fname, lname
FROM Patients
NATURAL JOIN Vaccinations
NATURAL JOIN Vaccines
GROUP BY NHI_id, fname, lname
HAVING count(DISTINCT vaccine_name) > 1
```

should do it.